# Get foreign key in external content type to show up in list view using Visual Studio

Tags: sharepoint-server, visual-studio, external-content-type, external-list

How can I setup external content types in such a way that when in the list view of these external content types, I can jump between and possible lookup values to that other type?
***Note: No 3rd party solution(like BCS MetaMan) or SharePoint Designer***

SharePoint External List– Using the Picker for Foreign Keys
Thanks.